# Nest StrLen and ifthenelse commands

Tags: conditionals, strings

Here is a sample of code I am working on:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}

\StrLen{123456}\\                                    %Prints 6      
\ifthenelse{\equal{6}{6}}{TRUE}{FALSE}\\              %Prints True
%\ifthenelse{\equal{\StrLen{123456}}{6}}{TRUE}{FALSE} %Want to print true


\end{document}
```

I am trying to nest a command inside another command. In this case the `\StrLen` command inside the `\ifthenelse` command. Is there a way to get around the problem I am running into?

Answer (score 10):

The problem with your attempt and the solution are explained in the `xstring` documentation:

> The macros of this package are not
>   purely expandable, i.e. they cannot be
>   put in the argument of an \edef.
>   Nestling macros is not possible
>   neither.
>
> For this reason, all the macros
>   returning a result (i.e. all excepted
>   the tests) have an optional argument
>   in last position. The syntax is [ name
>   ], where name is the name of the
>   control sequence that will receive the
>   result of the macro: the assignment is
>   made with an \edef which make the
>   result of the macro name purely
>   expandable. Of course, if an optional
>   argument is present, the macro does
>   not display anything.

Thus, the solution is to use the optional argument of `\StrLen` to store the length in a command and then use this command inside `ifthenelse`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand\CompLen[1]{%
  \StrLen{#1}[\MyStrLen]% we find the length of the string and store it in \MyStrLen
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\MyStrLen}{6}}% we compare the length of the string with 6
        {TRUE}{FALSE}}

\begin{document}

\CompLen{123456}
\CompLen{123}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you're testing numbers, you want

```
\ifthenelse{\StrLen{123456} = 6}{TRUE}{FALSE}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because `\StrLen` isn't fully expandable, i.e. requires assignments.